Relationship between $C^*$-algebras generated by translation and convolution operators
Let $ G $ be a locally compact abelian group. Consider the translation operators on $ L^2(G) $ defined by $ T_g f(x) = f(gx) $ for $ g \in G $. Denote the C*-algebra generated by these operators as $ A $.
Now, let $ h(x) \in L^1(G) $ and consider the convolution operators on $ L^2(G) $ defined by $ (f * h)(x) = \int_G f(y) h(y^{-1}x) \, dy $. Denote the C*-algebra generated by these operators along with the identity operator as $ B $.
Question:
Is it true that $ A $ and $ B $ are equal or is there a containment relation between them? I believe this question is closely related to Fourier analysis on locally compact abelian groups, but I have not studied that area in depth.
I may not have a precise understanding of some definitions, and it’s possible that my question is stated incorrectly. Corrections are welcome.

Also, I don’t have time to write a full answer now, but I’m pretty sure the answer is no unless $G$ is discrete, as Dirac measures are far from any $L^1$ function. But just for an easy counterexample where $A \not\subset B$, just take $G = \mathbb{R}$. Then $A$ is non-separable while $B$ is separable.

These are just some thoughts of what I tried and too long for a comment. Sadly not a real answer…
Using some Urysohn argument you can find for a neighbourhood basis $\mathcal U$ of some $g\in G$ a family $(f_U)_{U\in\mathcal U}$ such that $f_U\in C_c^+(G),\ \text{supp} f_U \subseteq U$ and $\|f_U\|_1=1$. You can then check that $\|f_U*h-h(g\,\cdot)\|_1 \to 0$ as $U\to\{g\}$ for arbitrary $h\in L^1(G)$. Thus the operators $T_{f_U}$ defined by $T_{f_U} h = f_U * h$ satisfy $T_{f_U} \to T_g$ pointwise. In general this convergence will not be in norm since the regular representation $G\to \mathcal{L}(L^2(G)), g\mapsto T_{g^{-1}}$ is never norm continuous (only strongly continuous) unless $G$ is discrete, so sadly I don‘t know if there‘s something to get via this approach…
If $G$ is discrete then $T_{g^{-1}} = T_{\delta_g}$ with $T_{\delta_g}h = \delta_g * h$ with the delta function $\delta_g(x) = 1$ iff $g=x$ and $0$ otherwise. Thus in this case $A\subseteq B$ and even $A=B$ by decomposing an arbitrary $f\in L^1(G)$ into a finite linear combination of delta functions.
